# Requesting Multiple Facebook Images from the facebook API in SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api, swift

I want to be able to request multiple photos using the facebook API. So far I am able to request the profile photo with the following code:

```
  let FBSession = PFFacebookUtils.session()
  let accessToken = FBSession.accessTokenData.accessToken
  let url = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1&access_token="+accessToken)

  let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

   NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
                        response, data, error in

                let fbImageData = data
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                self.profilePic.image = image
```

This works perfectly and allows me to access my current profile picture. But If I want to be able to access say the 5 most recent profile pictures how would I request that?

thanks in advance.